# eof bit not set even if offset is beyond file size

Tags: c++, fstream, eof

I have a fstream pointer fileP_.
I open a file with:
`fileP_.open(filePath_.c_str(), std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);`
I have a `Read()` function with it's definition as:
`int Read(size_t offset, char *buffer, size_t *size)`
So here I read `@size` in `@buffer` starting from offset `@offset` of a file.
My code of `Read()` is somewhat like this:

```
int rc = 0
fileP_.seekg(offset);  
fileP_.read(buffer, *size);  
if (!fileP_.gcount()) {  
  if (fileP_.eof())  
    *size = rc;   
  else if (fileP_.fail())  
    rc = -EIO;  
....
```

The code works fine until `offset < filesize`, but if I give `offset > filesize` `gcount()` gives `0`(which is expected) but I get `-EIO`, and I expect that if `offset > filesize` `size = rc = 0`.
Am I missing anything in the above code?
Thanks!

Comment: If you seekg > filesize the operation fails, the failbit is set and read does not work... (eof has not been set)

Comment: Ooh, I am new to c++ and there's lot of confusion on my side when the particular bits are. Changed the code to check if failbit is set after seekg(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AntonioGarrido can you please guide me if any more checks are required in the above code if I have missed any checks?

Comment: It is difficult to change your code. ¿what is rc? why you change *size? why you write "*size=rc" instead of "*size=0"?

Comment: C++ streams detect end of file when a read attempt **fails** because the stream is at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you seekg > filesize the operation fails, the failbit is set and read does not work... (eof has not been set)

If one operation fails, failbit is activated and all the following operation will be no-op until state bits are cleared. In this case, if seekg fails, istream::read will not read anything and, in particular, will not set eofbit.

On the other hand, eofbit is not activated when the position in the file is "at the end". Actually, it is activated when the stream detects the end of file, that is, when it try to gets the next char and an EOF is returned.

In general, in C++ it is not a good idea to control the end of input with eofbit. It is better to test if the operation has been successfull. When the operation fails, then test if the problem is the end of file by using eofbit.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot! :-)